# Get UTF-8 bytes from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, sha1

I have a requirement to "Perform the SHA1 hashing on the UTF-8 bytes of a string".  I'm not sure how to get the UTF-8 bytes out.  Here's an example of what I *should* get:

```
original = "http://www.provider.com/article?query=mysearch&abcd&1300459467&our secret key"
#Perform the sha1 hashing on the UTF-8 bytes of this string, to get ... 
expected_hashed = "99802fec87b6ef1d45bd07f3053d13 6cfcfbdf0b"
#... which is a 160 byte fingerprint.
#You need to then take the 20 byte representation of this string (make sure you're 
#not just taking the hex string), and base 64 encode that.
expected_encoded = "mYAv7Ie27x1FvQfzBT0TbPz73ws="
```

It's getting from `original` to `expected_hashed` that's giving me the problem: I don't know how to get the UTF-8 bytes out.  I'm doing SHA1 hashing like `Digest::SHA1.digest(unhashed_string)` and I'm not 100% sure that's appropriate in this instance either. :/  I'm also unsure about what the "20 byte representation of this string" would be.

Comment: Actually figured out the utf-8/hashing part: if i do `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(unhashed_string)` that gives me the expected_hashed value.  I still don't know what the 20 byte representation of this means though.

Comment: `ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-23 patchlevel 110) [x86_64-linux]` (it's an old server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'digest'
require 'base64'
Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest(original)[0,20])
# => "mYAv7Ie27x1FvQfzBT0TbPz73ws=\n"
```

Comment: Or you can just do:
Digest::SHA1.base64digest original